# How to import a sqlite db?

Tags: android

am trying to import a sqlite db in android studio application..i have done a  backup in my devices memory...when am trying to import a db in my application am getting message import failed.Please help me to import my db in my application

I did a backup in the folder:dbname.db

```
private void importDB() {
    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
        if (sd.canWrite()) {

            System.out.println("KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK");
            String currentDBPath = "//data//" + getPackageName() + "//databases//" +"dbname.db" ;
            String backupDBPath = "Restore.db"; // From SD directory.

            System.out.println("HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH");
            File backupDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
            File currentDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);
            System.out.println("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAaa");
            FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
            FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
            System.out.println("FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFH");
            src.close();
            dst.close();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Import Successful!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Import Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();

    }
}
```

Comment: Post your error logs too. i.e. the exception you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the below steps to solve the restore SQlite DB

1. add file.db into project/assets folder;
2. Create LinnaeusDatabase class:

   ```
     public class LinnaeusDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

     private static String DATABASE_NAME = "Dragonfly.db";
     public final static String DATABASE_PATH =
       "/data/data/com.kan.linnaeus/databases/";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private SQLiteDatabase dataBase;
    private final Context dbContext;

   public LinnaeusDatabase(Context context) {
   super(context, DBActivity.DatabaseName, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
   this.dbContext = context;
   DATABASE_NAME = DBActivity.DatabaseName;
   // checking database and open it if exists
   if (checkDataBase()) {
       openDataBase();
   } else {
       try {
           this.getReadableDatabase();
           copyDataBase();
           this.close();
           openDataBase();

       } catch (IOException e) {
           throw new Error("Error copying database");
       }
       Toast.makeText(context, "Initial database is created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
    }

   private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
   InputStream myInput = dbContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
   String outFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
   OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
   int length;
   while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
       myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
   }

   myOutput.flush();
   myOutput.close();
   myInput.close();
   }

     public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
   String dbPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
   dataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
   }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
   SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
   boolean exist = false;
   try {
       String dbPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
       checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null,
               SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
   } catch (SQLiteException e) {
       Log.v("db log", "database does't exist");
   }

   if (checkDB != null) {
       exist = true;
       checkDB.close();
   }
   return exist;
    }
     }
   ```

Comment: What is file.db